# Rate your experience

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got this popup about rating my experience when programming Java in VSCode (v1.70.0) on Linux. The link takes you to research.net and the questions are pretty simple (rate from 1-10, would you recommend to friends? positive/negative feedback). I have never installed any extension, ever.

My question is if this is normal and if it happens to a lot o people, because in years that's the first time I see something like this and I wonder why VSCode would hand out a link to a site like research.net and not to a Microsoft site.

Also, is there a switch to turn off feedback questions like these or opt-out of such improvement campaigns?

Is there an official article or a blog post about this, somewhere?

[These are the pages I refer to (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aresearch.net+vscode+%22rate+your+experience%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old [issue in the VSCode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51353) where the authors mention that the **Don't Show Again** button was hidden under the gear icon.